# PyCharm doesn't output needed data

Tags: python

I'm a bit confused, why my doesn't work in PyCharm, actually, it works, but there doesn't output needed data, I've checked it out in the shell, the code is executed properly. What could be the reason? or reasons? Would be thankful for help

```
  def search4vowels(word:str) -> set:
            """Return any vowels found in a supplied word."""
            vowels = set('aeiou')
            return vowels.intersection(set(word))

   search4vowels('function expect')
```

Comment: You need to print the returned value.

Answer (score 2):

```
 def search4vowels(word:str) -> set:
            """Return any vowels found in a supplied word."""
            vowels = set('aeiou')
            return vowels.intersection(set(word))

   print(search4vowels('function expect'))
```

You are basically just returning the vowels, but you need to do something with that, either print it or save it using a variable.

Comment: thanks, now it works, but so why in the shell i don't need to print it, i can just call this function?

Comment: That is the way the shell works. You can use it as a Python-powered calculator by typing an expression. That can be something simple like `1+1` or it can be a complex function call. The interpreter evaluates what you type and if it is not `None`, prints a representation of the value. But when you run a program you can't rely on the interpreter's read-eval-print loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys, I got it